# Camera settings to simulate miniature scale model

Tags: rendering, camera

I want to render an animation of a scene with multiple buildings and smaller details such that the scene will look like a miniature scale model.

The concept is probably the same as for [miniature faking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_faking), but unfortunately my knowledge of cameras, lenses and alike is still pretty rough, so I wanted to ask if you can provide me with quick tricks and tips about how to obtain such effect in Blender.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/88977/599

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is just to find the real life values - as a ballpark, try scaling your model down to the 'model' size that you want, somewhere in the order of 10cm. You might want to adjust the blender grid and unit settings to make this easier to work with. The only other thing left to do is choose an aperture.

Generally photographers might use a wide aperture (low number) to get this effect. Start from 2.8 and see if it is too much/not enough. From there, adjust the focus distance, aperture and model scale to fine tune the result.

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider accepting it so that others can quickly find the answer. Hope it helped.